# Make subdomain use main domain files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I hope someone has some insight on this.

I've got two domains:
domain.com
cl.domain.com

cl.domain.com is actually a Spanish version of the same site. Both domains use the same files, CMS, and database.

We've got some code that changes all of the menus and information over to Spanish based on what domain is being used.

Right now, when I type in "cl.domain.com" it redirects to "domain.com".

That's not what we need. We need for the site to remain on cl.domain.com.

Also, when I click on the Spanish language block to goto the Spanish site, I'm getting https://cl.domain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi with a big "SORRY" at the top.

It seems like maybe an issue with the htaccess file, but I'm not sure.

This has been working just fine for two years but all of sudden it stopped.

How can I make cl.domain.com and domain.com use the same files and stop the redirect from happening? People should remain on cl.domain.com if they go to that subdomain, but use the same files from domain.com.

I think the issue is somewhere in this part of the htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.com*
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,P]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cl\.
    RewriteRule ^ https://cl.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]


  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There. I posted my htaccess. Please reverse your downvote. A simple message asking me to revise my question would have been sufficient.

Comment: It looks like you are using Drupal and perhaps it was updated recently and the sites.php file was changed. sites.php resides in the sites directory under where Drupal is installed. That file is used to tell Drupal what directory to look in to find things based on the domain name.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the comment. It is Drupal. Site wasn't updated, but I haven't thought about maybe checking the settings.php file to see if there was a way that I could configure the subdomain in there.

Comment: Can you tell me what version of Apache you're running? I've noticed a lot of people have upgraded to 2.4 lately and it has caused them problems.